# How to make grub.cfg writeable automatically after every update-grub

Tags: grub2, grub

How can I ensure that my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is still writable after every run of `update-grub`?

I already tried to set permissions of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` like I want them to have, in a `41_custom` script, as I saw that the `grub-mkconfig` just moves this `.new` file to the final one, after everything out of `grub.d` has been included, but that did not result in keeping permissions finally.
Now I am still looking for an update-safe way to automatically have `grub.cfg` group writable after each run of `update-grub`.

(Background: I want to change the file via script before hibernating, and switch back to original after resuming.)

Comment: The question is really confusing. What are exactly your problems, why you are toying with grub (you should not), and why are doing this in the first place, and writable by whom? root is always able to write it.

Comment: The problem is that the permissions of /boot/grub/grub.cfg do not allow any writing to the file after every run of update-grub. My user script to hibernate wants to replace the file with another one, before hibernating, which it is not able to do without write permissions. So it would be nice to have a possibility to change the permissions automatically with every run of update-grub.

Comment: And if you look at the end of grub-mkconfig, you see that it creates /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new which is then mv'ed to /boot/grub/grub.cfg, so the (not working) idea had been to change the permissions of /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new so that /boot/grub/grub.cfg will later have the wished permissions. Unfortunately somewhere during update-grub the permissions are changed later again to read-only. So I should toy around with grub some more ;-) But how exactly?

Comment: why changing grub for sleeping?

Comment: Because I want to. Uh – I mean: multi-boot environment, and it otherwise often happens, that someone starts the wrong system although this will get us in difficulties with the hibernated one. (And sticky notes at the screen are note the preferred option to protect from this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a wrapper script for it.

You could do something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
update-grub
chmod g+w /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Then name it something like `update-grub-perm` (or whatever) and run it instead.

---

To have this script ran automatically after an `apt-get`, you can edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or create a new file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` and invoke your wrapper script with a `DPkg::Post-Invoke`.

For example, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80updgrubperm`:

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke {"/root/bin/update-grub-perm";};
```

And `/root/bin/update-grub-perm` could be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE='/boot/grub/grub.cfg'
DATE=$(date '+%s')
FILETIME=$(stat -c %Y $FILE)
DAYSEC=86400

if [ $FILETIME -ge $(expr $DATE - $DAYSEC) ]; then
    chmod g+w $FILE
fi

exit 0
```

Where the script above checks if `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` has been modified in the past 24-hours. If so, it `chmod`'s.

**Note**: You can probably come up with a better way to check if `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` has been updated, but this is a quick example. With my quick research, I didn't see any `apt` or `dpkg` options for *run this script if this specific package is updated*.

---

**Reference**: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-hook-a-script-command-to-apt-get-upgrade-command/

Comment: How would I tell grub to call it automatically after every run of update-grub (e.g. during the system updates)?

Comment: @Jaleks: What distro are you using?

Comment: Debian 9 currently

Comment: @Jaleks: Check my edits on the answer.

Comment: TYVM, as I never need to care if grub.cfg has been changed, the additional script is nice, but DPkg::Post-Invoke should do it already, thx